# How to implement unlock button to add root privileges?

Tags: linux, user-interface, authentication, gnome

How can I add a unlock button as shown in following dialog box, to authenticate and then switch to root privileges?

[image]

To execute my application as a root, I am currently using `pkexec`, but in this way we can authenticate while launching application. It would be great if application will be launched as a non-root user, and if required, user can click and add root privileges to running application.

Is there any command or system call I have to call after clicking this unlock button? If yes, then is it desktop environment specific?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is gnome policy kit i.e. for debian https://packages.debian.org/jessie/policykit-1-gnome

Comment: @HRgiger, Thanks! I used it to authenticate user before starting app using `pkexec`, how can it be used to authenticate user while running the application?